# Why resizing an image smoothed by Gaussian by factor of 2 also increase sigma by factor of 2

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, sift

In the paper about SIFT algorithm ([Distinctive Image Features
from Scale-Invariant Keypoints](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Elowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf)) it says at the end of section 3.3:

> We double the size of the input image using linear interpolation prior to building the first level of the pyramid. [...]. We assume that the original image has a blur of at least σ = 0.5 (the minimum needed to prevent significant aliasing), and that therefore the doubled image has σ = 1.0 relative to its new pixel spacing.

The paper says that when doubling the size of an image smoothed by a Gaussian with σ = 0.5, the new image doubles its spread, so σ = 1.0 in the new image.

I can understand intuitively why it can be true, and I also checked it in Matlab to see the effect. However, I can't prove it to myself mathematically.

I'll be happy to see proof or a direction to reference that can help me understand it mathematically.

Answer (score 4):

A first discrete is pixel wise: imagine an image with only one active pixel. If you upsample it by two in both directions, you get a $2\times 2$ pixel block. Below, I did not extend the size of the right-hand side image, as it is all black.  [image: Double size image]
Now, think of a natural image of a linear combination of many single-pixel images.

A second more continuous vision is to consider the image as a function $f$. It can be treated separately in each $x$ and $y$ directions. A measure of spread $\varsigma$ for $f(x)$ would be:

$$ \varsigma = \sqrt{\int \mathrm{d}x f^2(x)}\,.$$

Then, the double-sized image would be represented by $f(x/2)$. A change of variable will give you a $2\varsigma$ spread. The same reasoning would work in two dimensions, if you integrate $f(x,y)$ and $f(x/2,y/2)$.